# What is the phrase for :I should do a task in two days?

Tags: phrases

I want a simple phrase to describe this:

If **I should do a task in two days** then which phrase is more natural to use:

2 Days deadline

2 Days Grace period

or a better phrase you recommend...

...

Comment: A grace period extends a deadline.

Comment: you are hoping to do so in 2 days or you are allowed 2 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**time limit** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/time+limit) or a *deadline* could work .

> a period of time within which something must be done or completed.

*I should do the task in two days, the time limit allowed. Or:
 I should do the task in two days, the deadline.*